# How can I fix a missing permission for an outside resource in a CRM2011 custom workflow running in the sandbox?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

My custom workflow fails when it attempts to connect to an SQL database - NOT the CRM database, but another one, which happens to be on the same server instance.  I am attempting to open a connection with these credentials, which work from SSMS:

```
string strConnect = "server=vm-tlsdev-data;database=TLS_Match;user id=ContactMatch.Test;password=c8NFrZ7L;Trusted_Connection=false;";

SqlConnection sqlClient = newSqlConnection(strConnect);
sqlClient.Open();
```

The Open() method fails:

*Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): TP24408ContactMatch.Workflow.ContactMatch: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxCodeUnit.Execute(IExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.ProxyCustomActivity.Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)*

I've looked for similar issues and they lead me to wonder whether the problem is getting permission to 'see' outside the sandbox.  I cannot think of a viable way to change the architecture so that everything is either inside CRM or outside it; I need to cross the boundary somewhere and the workflow is the obvious place.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this isn't running in CRM Online, which I presume is the case because your SQL connection is not a FQDN, you should be able to register the DLL containing the custom workflow activity to run in full trust (not the sandbox.)

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I wonder whether you could point me towards instructions / guidance please?  I am working remotely from the server but we are both in the same VPN.

Comment: When you register the assembly containing your custom workflow code using the Plugin Registration Tool make sure that box # 3, Specify the Isolation Mode, is set to None. You'll need to be a Deployment Administrator on the CRM server (configured by running the Deployment Manager) to register this plugin.

Comment: @SimonSellick - Did this work for you? Are you still have this issue?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response @Nicknow, I am still waiting for acknowledgement from the supplier who manages the server that we can try this approach.  I will update this posting when I have a result, but meanwhile, thank you again for your suggestion.

Comment: @SimonSellick - Okay, if the supplier won't allow you to do this and requires that all DLLs run in Sandbox mode you won't be able to make direct SQL calls from your plugin code. It is a security limitation of Sandbox. You would need to call a web service which would then make the SQL call - time consuming but not difficult to develop.

Comment: Well, that was a marathon - 8 weeks - but the supplier has now given me the Deployment Administrator role and I can register the plug-in to run with Isolation Mode set to None; I confirm that the workflow can now get at the external database.  Thanks again for your help.  I just need to get my code to work now...

Answer (score 0):

I would presume that some application might be using the external database that you are trying to connect to. 
Why don't you create a web service that will get the required data for you from that external data source and then you consume this service in a CRM web-resource and process your logic.
If not a web-resource then there is always an option to call that service from custom workflow activity.

The problem that you are seeing is because of the logical boundary of sand-boxing.

Comment: Nothing else will be using the external db, it exists solely for this workflow to use.  The workflow starts a stored procedure in the external db.  That proc references both locally-held and CRM-hosted data, then does a lot of heavy stuff with it before spitting out a results set which the workflow then uses to update some CRM records.  The process logic of the stored proc is very intensive and needs to run within SQL Server, so I am not sure how creating a web service would help - but anyway, I don't have access to the server at that level, only SQL access (and that was grudgingly granted).

Comment: If you can provide a little more details on the requirements as in (what needs to be done when kinda stuff) I might help you figure out a better solution to it. This sure sounds like an interesting stuff that you want to achieve here.

Comment: It's a matching process: users import a list of names, addresses etc via an Excel template, into a custom table.  The workflow runs a SQL proc that matches these records according to about 50 rules, against CRM contacts, accounts and jobs (connections in our CRM) and returns candidate matches with a confidence score.  Those exceeding a minimum score (user input param) get the guid of the matched contact/account populated.  As the relationships between contact/account and the custom table is known to CRM, these matched records can then be used as a known 'fact' in a marketing list query.

Answer (score 0):

The only type of communication from within the Sandbox is HTTP/HTTPS. You cannot access the registry, file system, SQL databases etc.

You will also find certain DLLs can't be referenced or ILMerged into the Sandbox.

If you want to connect to an SQL database within your plugin or workflow it will have to be registered full trust.